# problems with authorization in social networks

Tags: android, ios5

We are faced with this problem - cordova is not able to access Windows authorization through social networks on the mobile assemblies. After you install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser app learned how to simulate the opening of Windows, but all the addresses authorization through social networks open assemblies with the prefix file:\ instead of https:\ and as a result authorization for the assemblies is not working. Now we are trying  to solve the problem using the ngCordova library, there is no result yet. There are  many things in the app which need changing. And this option will only work for mobile builds. It is necessary to figure out how to keep working login function on the desktop.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask